# how to change the Download path in iphone mobile iOS using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, download

I use to download the file.The file format is (png, jpeg, pdf, doc, docx). when I download the file, I get the path is in my console  -

**file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD156B4B-D59C-4D0A-89F1-5D96F0E55580/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.demo.projectname/CFNetworkDownload_D0xbAq.tmp**

When I upload a pdf, doc, docx format it show same location how to find the location in our file. I need to change the location and file format all so.
can you please help me ?
I once download finished I show the file downloaded file. how can I hate this. please help me. i don't know this. this is new one for me.

My attached code is

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjtcr16sc7ygf3y/DownloadManager.swift?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7n8mb20115ncan/AddressProofVC.swift?dl=0]

Answer (score 0):

After you get this url, you can use `FileManager.default.moveItem(at: currentUrl, to: aimUrl)`

and the `aimUrl` is actually what you want, you can set the location and the file format.

Comment: Hi NF Lee, How to set the mobile location in aimUrl??

Comment: Let say if you wanna store it in `document directory`, then the url will be `URL.init(string: "file://" + NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! + "file.fromat")`

Comment: I use like this but it not working  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {debugPrint("Download finished: \(location)")
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location)
        let file_formet = ".\(appDelegate.path_location)" let aimUrl = URL.init(string: "file://" + NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! + "file.fromat")
        try? FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: aimUrl!)
    }

Comment: As I can see you removed the file in first place, you should not remove the file before you use it.

Comment: I hide the  //try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location) but still no response in my iCode Drive